# What will be the locus of the intersection point of two tangents to $x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}=a^{2/3}$ that are perpendicular to each other?

Tags: calculus, geometry, locus

> If $(a\cos^3 m, a\sin^3 m)$ is a point on the curve $x^{\frac{2}{3}} + y^{\frac{2}{3}} = a^{\frac{2}{3}}$, then find the locus of the intersection point of two tangents that are perpendicular to each other.

---

My try: I have tried it by taking by two different points. But it got too tedious to proceed. Can anyone please help me giving some easier solution.

Answer (score 3):

I'll give you a hint: use the rotation symmetry of the astroid together with the fact that the slope is monotone on each quadrant to force $m\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$ are the only points whose tangent is perpendicular to that of point cooresponding to parameter $m$.

Comment: In the parametric equation of an astroid what is m?  @user10354138

Comment: I'm just using the same notation as your question, i.e. $(x(m),y(m))=(a\cos^3 m,a\sin^3m)$ is the parametric equation we are using.

Answer (score 2):

I'm expanding on the hint provided by  @user10354138 :

Let $a=1$. Then 
$$t\mapsto z(t):=\bigl(\cos^3 t,\sin^3 t\bigr)\qquad(t \ {\rm mod}\ 2\pi)$$
is a parametric representation of the full astroid $\alpha$. Here the variable $t$ is just "time"; it has no geometric significance in the following. Note that $t\mapsto t+{\pi\over2}$ rotates $\alpha$ by ${\pi\over2}$ counterclockwise. It follows that the tangents at $z(t)$ and $z\bigl(t+{\pi\over2}\bigr)$ are orthogonal.

We now fix a $t$. Then the two mentioned tangents $g_i$ have parametric representations
$$\eqalign{g_1:\quad u\mapsto w_1(u)&:=z(t)+ u z'(t)\qquad\qquad\qquad(-\infty<u<\infty),\cr g_2:\quad v\mapsto w_2(v)&:=z\bigl(t+{\pi\over2}\bigr)+ v z'\bigl(t+{\pi\over2}\bigr)\qquad(-\infty<v<\infty)\ .\cr}$$
Compute the point of intersection $p:=g_1\wedge g_2$ of these two lines. This point will then be a function of the chosen $t$. In fact $t\mapsto p(t)$ is a parametric representation of the locus we are looking for.

Here is a figure:

[image]

Comment: I did not get you. What is alpha? How it is rotating when t changes? Please elaborate it.@Christian Blatter

Comment: As stated $\alpha$ is the full  astroid with arcs in every quadrant. –  Already the other answer has made reference to a ${\pi\over2}$-rotation under $t\mapsto t+{\pi\over2}$. – Maybe you should really think about the whole problem yourself a little. **Draw a figure!**